# Find Elements of a Quotient Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a group $Z_{24}$, I have two subgroups $H = \langle 4\rangle$ and $N = \langle 6\rangle$. I computed the elements of $H$ to be $\{0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20\}$ and elements of $N$ to be $\{0, 6, 12, 18\}$. I computed $HN$ by multiplying each element of $H$ with each element of $N$, yielding $\{0, 2, 4, 6,\ldots, 20, 22\}$.

How would I go about calculating $HN/N$? I know $|N| = 4, |HN| = 12,$ so $|HN/N|$ should be $3$. Is it valid to take a random element in HN, say $2$, and multiply $2$ by $N$? $N$ is $\{0, 6, 12, 18\}$ so $2N = \{2, 8, 14, 20\}$? In addition, is it possible to have an odd number of cosets (e.g. $3$)? Is the index supposed to indicate the number of left/right cosets or the number of left +right cosets?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First how are you saying |$HN$|=$12$. It will be $24$? Do you know second Isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Yep, I'm familiar with the second isomorphism theorem. This question actually has 2 more parts: find elements of H|(H union N) and then show that the two groups are isomorphic (basically the 2nd isomorphism theorem). Could you explain why |HN|=24? I am referring to the cardinality of HN, and there are 12 elements in HN.

Comment: Oh yeah I considered cartesian product. sorry. $HN$ will have $12$ elements. so what seems to be problem here, if you do second iso theorem first and just use it then.

Comment: You are saying $HN/N \cong H/(H \cup N)$. No that it is not. second iso says that $HN/N \cong  H/N \cap H$. In your case that will come out to be $3$ as you have calculated, which is $|HN/N|$ It is possible to have odd index and it denotes either the number of left cosets or right cosets as both is the same number.